# How does ArangoDB work for efficient gragh traversal

Tags: arangodb

I am new to ArangoDB. After reading the official document, I know ArangoDB's graph feature uses `edge collection` to define the relations between vertices with `_from` and `_to` attribute,which will refer to the start and end vertex.
Index will be created on these two attributes automatically for fast access.

With this structure, the performance of gragh traversal will heavily depend on efficiency of the index defined on the `from_` and `to_` attribute, but it looks that the index alone is not enough to support efficient gragh traversal?

I have thought that given a vertex, only a small subset of the vertices will be involved to traverse (like traversing a linked list for given a node),  but with index and edge collection structure, the whole edge collection will be involved to do the query(although the index would help to avoid traverse the whole table from the first document to the end document).

Also, when solving a practical problem with graph, there may be many vertices to visit, even with the help of index, it also would  inevitablely cause bad performance.

So, I would ask with the edge collection structure, how ArangoDB is implemented for efficient graph traversal

Comment: Could someone help answer this question? I am evaluating to choose one graph engine.

Comment: It depends on the specifics of your use case. Do you have a dataset that you can use to test some basic AQL queries against? The size of that database will also help you determine the CPU Core / RAM requirements that would be optimal, but to really get a realistic number, you need to load some test data and try it against different technologies.

I wouldn't use 'how' they do it as a selector for what is the best technology, rather think about your use case and how well their technology solution aligns with your use case.

Comment: Thanks @DavidThomas for your answer , but my question would only focus on the code level how graph travel is implemented with the edge collection struture for fast gragh  traversal, it is irrelevant with CPU or memory.